# Spring session bean initialization on event

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, session-bean

In my project i need SessionBean to store objects associated with current session. On Session is created and user is authenticated i want to set objects to my bean.

Bean definition:

```
<bean scope="session" class="org.example.SessionBean">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Authentication Listener:

```
public class SpringAuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

private LogService logService;

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SessionBean sessionBean;

public SpringAuthenticationListener(LogService logService, UserService userService) {
    this.logService = logService;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent e) {
    LogEvent logEvent = new LogEvent();

    if (e instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
        AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) e;
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        User loggedUser = userService.getUser( userDetails.getUsername() );
        sessionBean.setLoggedUser(loggedUser);
    } 
}
```

}

But, problem is that i can't getting an instance of current SessionBean instance. That's my error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.org.example.SessionBean#0': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

How should i do this ? What event or listener will let me initialize SessionBean with current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security operates using a `Filter` filters are executed before any `Servlet` and as such also before the `DispatcherServlet`. To be able to use `request` or `session` scoped beans a `RequestContext` is needed. This is normally prepared by the `DispatcherServlet`. When wanting to use scoped beans outside of the `DispatcherServlet` you need to do some additional setup. As also stated by the exception:

> use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

To fix add a [`RequestContextListener`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) or [`RequestContextFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) to your `web.xml`. When using the latter make sure it is executed before the `springSecurityFilterChain` else it won't take effect. The listener is always executed before any filter.